# How can I write regex code to remove all two digit numbers in a string?

Tags: regex

I don't know how regex works, I tried

```
s = s.replace(\[10-99]\,"");
```

Comment: All 2 digit numbers = `(?<!\d)\d\d(?!\d)`

Comment: This is javascript? Shouldnt the backslashes be forward? `[10-99]` allows `1`, `9`, and the range of `0` through `9`. `\d` or `[0-9]` should be the same thing. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MasonWang please edit your question to make it complete.  Please declare what language you will be using this regex in, post a few sample inputs, and your expected output for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex `(?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\d)`, if You want skip from 0 to 9 use this one `(?<!\d)[1-9][0-9](?!\d)`

Comment: First, you need `/g`, and second - it will remove also all 4-digit, 6-digit, and so on numbers, not just 2-digit numbers.